# MongoDB log: extent 0:550000 and can't find plugin [desc]

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am using Meteor with a separate MongoDB running on Windows. I ran MongoDB as a service.

My MongoDB log is full of the following:

```
Mon Mar 04 14:15:36 [conn19] info DFM::findAll(): extent 0:55000 was empty, skipping ahead. ns:webfm.graphdata
Mon Mar 04 14:15:38 [conn17] info DFM::findAll(): extent 0:55000 was empty, skipping ahead. ns:webfm.graphdata
Mon Mar 04 14:15:40 [conn16] info DFM::findAll(): extent 0:55000 was empty, skipping ahead. ns:webfm.graphdata
Mon Mar 04 14:15:43 [conn18] warning: can't find plugin [desc]
Mon Mar 04 14:15:43 [conn19] info DFM::findAll(): extent 0:55000 was empty, skipping ahead. ns:webfm.graphdata
Mon Mar 04 14:15:49 [conn18] info DFM::findAll(): extent 0:55000 was empty, skipping ahead. ns:webfm.graphdata
Mon Mar 04 14:16:14 [conn16] warning: can't find plugin [desc]
Mon Mar 04 14:16:20 [conn17] info DFM::findAll(): extent 0:55000 was empty, skipping ahead. ns:webfm.graphdata
Mon Mar 04 14:16:24 [conn16] warning: can't find plugin [desc]

Mon Mar 04 14:16:32 [conn20] info DFM::findAll(): extent 0:60000 was empty, skipping ahead. ns:webfm.history
Mon Mar 04 14:16:34 [conn16] warning: can't find plugin [desc]
```

From what I can find the "findAll(): extent 0:55000..." seemed to have to do with my application's removing the data frequently. Is that correct?

How about the can't find plugin [desc]? What's that plugin? How can I fix it?

Comment: What version of MongoDB are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From what I can find the "findAll(): extent 0:55000..." seemed to have to do with my application's removing the data frequently. Is that correct?

Per Nick's answer, the message `extent 0:55000 was empty, skipping ahead` is related to your frequent deletions.  This is a warning emitted when skipping an empty data extent, with `0:55000` being the extent location.  The space will normally be reused as you add more data to that collection.

If you are frequently adding and deleting this collection and disk space is of concern, you could also consider:

- enabling [`usePowerof2Sizes`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/collMod/) flag for this collection (MongoDB 2.2 or newer) for more effective reuse of deleted space
- saving temporary collections in a separate database, and dropping the database when done (rather than running frequent compacts or repairs)

> How about the can't find plugin [desc]? What's that plugin? How can I fix it?

This typically means you have an invalid index definition and the index "plugin" can't be found to handle that.  In this example, I expect you have an indexed field declared with a property of `desc` rather than `-1`.

You can check the index definitions with [`db.collection.getIndexes()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.getIndexes/):

```
use webfm
db.graphdata.getIndexes()
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip of "usePowerOf2Sizes". I checked my log again and I don't see any of the "plugin [desc] warning any more. I must have somehow fixed the issue with the changes of my code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The message is in fact informational and harmless. It tells you that a whole extent was empty. This can happen if you deleted a lot of data recently.

You can use the [compact](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/compact/_) command to defragment and compact a collection (basically re-writing it to disk and re-creating the indexes on the collection), which would get rid of the log message. Please be aware that compact is a resource-heavy operation.

Comment: this is inline with what I have read and my application does remove data from that two collections frequently. Because the docs are removed as planned, I don't see any obvious benefits of running compact, I will continue seeing those log messages. I am actually moe interested at the "can't find plugin [desc]" warning.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not absolute sure this is a problem. You might be running mongodb with too much verbosity, so its showing excessive detail in its warnings and processes for debug reasons. This is a good thing, because if theres a problem or bug the issue can be identified.

But if you want to remove it:

Decrease the number of 'v's or remove them in your startup command.

If you use a config file change whichever of these you have to false:

```
vvvvv = false
vvvv = false
vvv = false
vv = false
v = false
```

Comment: My mongod.cfg file only has one line to setup my logpath. logpath=C:\mongodb\log\mongo.log